# Same statement yields NULL when in a stored function, and non-NULL valid result otherwise

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored function for calculating ELO ranking:

```
CREATE FUNCTION spodziewanyWynik(mój INT, przeciwnika INT)
RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE wynik DOUBLE;
  SET wynik = 
    1.0E0 / (1.0E0 + POWER(1.0E1, przeciwnika - mój + 0.0E0) / 4.0E2);
  RETURN wynik;
END//

CREATE FUNCTION nowyRanking(mój INT, przeciwnika INT, wynik DOUBLE)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE wynik INT;
  SET wynik = 
    mój + ROUND(3.0E1 * (wynik - spodziewanyWynik(mój, przeciwnika)));
  RETURN wynik;
END//
```

Now I want to test it. I run:

```
SELECT nowyRanking(1500, 1500, 0.0E0);
```

And I get a `NULL`, for reasons unknown to me.

And now the fun part. I run:

```
SELECT 1500 + ROUND(3.0E1 * (0.0E0 - spodziewanyWynik(1500, 1500)));
```

And I get: `1470`. Whew, that’s quite an improvement from a `NULL`, isn’t it?

Why on Earth does this happen? How should I fix my stored function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to the same variable name is used for the parameter and local variable. i.e, `wynik` used as `INT` in the local variable as well as `DOUBLE` in the parameter of the `nowyRanking` function.

In this case changing the parameter name will solve the issue. In the below code I renamed the parameter name `wynik DOUBLE` to `wynikDouble DOUBLE` and handled the same in the query to solve the problem.

**Answer** for *How should I fix my stored function?*

```
CREATE FUNCTION nowyRanking(mój INT, przeciwnika INT, wynikDouble DOUBLE)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE wynik INT;
  SET wynik = 
    mój + ROUND(3.0E1 * (wynikDouble - spodziewanyWynik(mój, przeciwnika)));
  RETURN wynik;
END
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76b5b/3

**Answer** for *Why on Earth does this happen?*

**Update:** In your actual code you declared the `wynik` as `INT` and used in the `SET wynik = mój + ROUND(3.0E1 * (wynik - spodziewanyWynik(mój, przeciwnika)));` block, here the `wynik` value is `NULL` only.

So the query is execute as `SELECT 1500 + ROUND(3.0E1 * (NULL - spodziewanyWynik(1500, 1500)));` that's why you are getting `NULL` as result.